# QMessageBox With HTML Layout Formatting

Tags: html, css, qt, qmessagebox

For my program, I'm doing a QMessageBox for the about section, and I import an html file to set the layout of the said box :

```
// Program.cpp
QMessageBox about;
about.setWindowTitle(tr("About"));

// Enable the HTML format.
about.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);

// Getting the HTML from the file
std::ifstream file("html/about.html");
std::string html, line;

if (file.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(file, line))
        html += line;
}

about.setText(html.c_str());
about.exec();
```

And the about.html is like this :

```
<!-- about.html -->
<div>
     <h1>The Program</h1>
     <p> Presentation </p>
     <p> Version : 0.1.2 </p>
     <p> <a href="www.wipsea.com">User Manual</a> </p>
     <h4>Licence Agreement</h4>
     <p style="border: 1px solid black; overflow: y;">
        Law thingy, bla and also bla, etc ...
     </p>
</div>
```

The problem is that I don't know what is possible, and what isn't.

For instance I want to put the licence agreement in a textarea with a border and an overflow.
The h1 & h4 works, yet the style for the licence agreement doesn't.

So the licence agreement is just plain text.

Is there a way to style the html in a QMessageBox ?

Comment: I believe the message boxes are suitable better for the short messages (texts). If you need to show extended text, such as license agreement, I think using `QTextEdit` is better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`QMessageBox` is just a convenience class and does not offer this functionality. You will have to construct your own dialog :

```
class HTMLMessageBox : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HTMLMessageBox(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void setHtml(QString html);

private:
    QTextEdit *m_textEdit;
};


HTMLMessageBox::HTMLMessageBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    m_textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    m_textEdit->setAcceptRichText(true);

    QPushButton *okButton = new QPushButton(tr("Ok"));
    searchButton->setDefault(true);

    QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton(tr("Cancel"));

    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(Qt::Horizontal);
    buttonBox->addButton(searchButton, QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole);
    buttonBox->addButton(cancelButton, QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole);

    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

    QVBoxLayout *lt = new QVBoxLayout;
    lt->addWidget(m_textEdit);
    lt->addWidget(buttonBox);

    setLayout(lt);
}

void HTMLMessageBox::setHtml(QString html)
{
    m_textEdit->setHtml(html);
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't do what I expect. The textEdit HTML is in a container with an overflow, but it contains the whole HTML. Plus, there's no border for the licence corpus.
The textEdit isn't better to parse HTML.